# Any simple way to test a @RequestBody method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

If I have a `@Controller` method whose parameter is a `@RequestBody` param, I usually have to write some jQuery script or something similar to perform an AJAX request with `JSON` object in order to call that method. If I tried calling that method via a web browser directly, it returns with a Error `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Is there any alternative to just quickly call such method using browser without having to write some `jQuery` code? Like perhaps a way to write the `JSON` object in the **URL/address bar?**

code:

```
@RequestMapping("testCall")
@ResponseBody
public List<TestObject> getTestCall (@RequestBody TestParams testParams) {
  return stuff;
}

public class TestParams {
  private Integer testNumber;
  //getter/setter for testNumber
}
```

I thought maybe I could just do:

```
http://localhost/testCall?testNumber=1
```

maybe Spring would auto populate a new TestParams instance with that property set to 1 but that didnt work...

maybe I need to do something extra for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a `@RequestBody` annotated parameters is for the Spring MVC stack to use the HTTP request body to produce an argument that will be bound to the parameter. As such, you need to provide a request body. Sending a request body is very atypical for a GET request. As such, browsers don't typically support it, at least not when simply entering an address in the address bar and submitting the request.

You'll need to use a different HTTP client, like jQuery. I typically have a small Java project in Eclipse that's setup with an Apache HTTP components client which can send HTTP requests to whatever server. It takes a few seconds/minutes to setup the correct request body and run.

Comment: Maybe I do not want @RequestBody then? Is there another tag that I could use where in the method signature it is an object, but the request itself is passing key/value pairs just like you would map to a PathParam variable except they are all properties of that one object? Spring would just populate an instance of your object with those query string properties?

Comment: @Trant What you want is up to you, but, yes, a `@ModelAttribute`  annotated parameter would be constructed from request parameters. These can be sent as part of the query string.

Comment: Thanks, ModelAttribute does the trick! Any idea why I cannot use JSONDeserializer in conjunction with ModelAttribute properties? Like if I have a date I want to send in a specific string format... Spring rejects it with 400 Bad Request and ignores any Deserializer annotation

Comment: @Trant Because Spring doesn't use any `HttpMessageConverter`s to do the conversion and therefore doesn't use Jackson. For dates, look into `DateTimeFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent the last year building a REST API, and by far the best way to exercise that API manually is using the Chrome Extension, Postman.  I cannot recommend this tool enough.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

To test your simple example you'll need to invoke a POST (I assume that as you have a request body, but your controller method doesn't define a HTTP Verb) using POSTMAN to your Url (like the following example):

```
POST /contextRoot/testCall
{
  "testNumber": 1
}
```

If you want to test your API automatically (which I recommend), you can use the excellent Spring Mvc Test project.  This allows your to call your API via a rest-like DSL and assert that the response is in the shape you want.  More details can be found here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework

Answer (score 0):

you can add request params to the getTestCall method:

```
@RequestParam(value = "testNumber", required = false, defaultValue = "") String testNumber
```

Comment: You mean, instead of using RequestBody? That won't help me as I need to work with objects not bunch of passed parameters... I know my example was too simply with one parameter but most of my actual situations involve objects that have many properties, so its mainly for keeping things concise we use RequestBody tag on an object

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome app called Advanced REST client. You can pass the data in form of json to your controller using this chrome app. For eg. json data is

id:1,

name:"xyz"

whereas the controller can have @RequestBody Person form.

The Person class would be a POJO having id and name as instance variables. The Spring would automatically map the json data to the form.

I think this is the easiest and simplest way of checking your spring controller.
[Check the extension Advanced REST client here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know You can send JSON object to the webbrowser and it will be displayed without further need of AJAX.

useful tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/